# The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet", determined from the Dynamic Web Module facet version (2.3), was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-orm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFZEd.jpg)its show error in my maven archetype web project plz tells me how to solve it.

I am trying to change my web version and adding dependencies but show some error. This problem is in jsp file there is no lib folder shows. and last one changing the library but still show error.

Comment: Which spring version does this concern? Also facet 2.3 version is quite old.

Comment: how to change facet version

Comment: Without knowing which Spring version you are targeting or server changing it randomly won't help. Add your `pom.xml` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to target Servlet API version 6, you **must** use Eclipse 2023-06, or newer, and set the Dynamic Web Module facet to version 6 on the project's Project Facets property page. If the facet is set *at all*, the JSP editor and validation will use the version value to decide what the default superclass will be for JSP files.

[image: The Project Facets property page on a dynamic web project]

Comment: there is dynamic web module show maximum 5 version show how to correct them.

Comment: Your version of the Spring Framework only needs version 5, which is supported by Tomcat 10.0.x. Version 6 of the facet only exists in the latest Eclipse release.

Comment: I will change version this show dynamic web module 5.0 required 1.8 or newer.

Comment: I solve this error using dependency injection Jakarta and javax  add in pom.xml file .

Comment: Did changing the facet version and rerunning validation not eliminate the Error?